# Why my JS Alert box is not displaying?

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code.

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){

$descript = $_POST{'descript'};
$type = $_POST{'type'};
$c_max = $_POST{'c_max'};
$status = $_POST{'status'};

$queryInsert = "INSERT INTO `item_master` (`Item`, `Descript`, `Type`, `C_max`, `Exist`, `Status`) VALUES ('$item', '$descript', '$type', '$c_max', '0', '$status');";
try{
    $resultInsert = mysqli_query($conn, $queryInsert);

    if($resultInsert)
    {
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Item Inserted");</script>';
            header ("Location: Insertion.php");
        }else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The item could not be inserted ");</script>';
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $ex){
    echo 'Error Delete '.$ex->getMessage();
}
```

}

My code works fine my query actually can insert new data in my DB but as the title said my "confirmation" `alert` is not displaying and I don't understand why. Before my `if(isser($_POST['save']))` a JS function runs and ask me if I really want to insert a new data. So obviously I have the pop alerts activated in my browser. So... Im I doing somthing wrong?

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: when you issue `header("Location: ...")`, the user is redirected as soon as the response gets to their machine so they're never going to see the page you're `echo`ing to.

Comment: `$_POST{'descript'}` syntax, syntax, syntax ................errors don't work fine.  -- OMG this works, why does this work! Dont get it. But forget this comment. I feel like a newbie know. Why...

Comment: I'm a real newbie in PHP so Why `$_POST{'descript'}` is supouse to fail? I really want to improve my code. @JustOnUnderMillions

Comment: No, im the newbie now, this is not documented anywhere (or did not found it), but normaly you use `$_POST['descript']`. And if i whre you i would use always `[]` instead of `{}`. Im coding know for many years in php. But i have seen this the first time, also the one that votes my comment up ;) so syntax is ok, but better switch all to `[]` :)

Comment: are you able to insert any record in your table. where is `$conn`.

Comment: I found it: `Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Thanks for the advise. I have just a couple of months using PHP and I saw a guy using the curly braces in a Youtube tutorial so I start to use them but I'll follow your advice.

Comment: @Suchit Yes, My code works fine. The issue is only my alert. But @castis is right about the `header`. I'll try to solve it with JS instead of PHP

Comment: There is SQL injection vulnerability in your code, you can not just paste post values into an Insert, this is really bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `window.location`(or other related options like:`window.location.href`).

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
        {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Item Inserted");window.location="Insertion.php";</script>';
}else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The item could not be inserted ");</script>';
        }
```